# Symfony simple Login form with the new authentication method not working

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I am having trouble setting up a new symfony application and I am sure its something about the new Authenticator-based Security system.

1. I installed a fresh symfony application, version 5.3.6.
2. Installed the security bundle `composer require symfony/security-bundle`(https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html).
   Followed all the steps there.
3. After that I wanted to build a simple
   login form following this guide:
   https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html. I
   executed the command `php bin/console make:auth` which generated all
   the files and updated my security.yml, as per usual. Here I notice
   that the command did not generate the Guard authenticator(since I
   understand its depracaded), but the new
   one(https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/authenticator_manager.html).
4. After this I go to my /login page, type the credentials and submit
   the form. The page reloads and nothing. No error message and I am
   still not authenticated. I did not do any additional steps, since it
   should work as it is? Well at least the old Guard authentication
   worked like that. However this new authentication system seems to
   not work. Am I missing something?

MY FILES:

LoginFormAuthenticator.php

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator{

use TargetPathTrait;

public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
{
    $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
}

public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
{
    $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

    $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge($email),
        new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
        [
            new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->get('_csrf_token')),
        ]
    );
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
{
    if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    // For example:
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('dashboard'));
}

protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
{
    return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
}
```

}

SecurityController.php

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController{

/**
 * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
 */
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{
    // if ($this->getUser()) {
    //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
    // }

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
 */
public function logout()
{
    throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
}
```

}

security.yml

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/experimental_authenticators.html
enable_authenticator_manager: true
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            # where to redirect after logout
            # target: app_any_route

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: What you posted looks right.  I assume you did tweak onAuthenticationSuccess as your posted code shows.  Try commenting out the admin access control line just to make sure it is not messing things up.

Comment: @Cerad The problem is, onAuthenticationSuccess does not even get called. Even more, the authenticate() method is not even called. I added `die;` to the authenticate method, submited the form and the page reloaded, meaning I didn`t even reach the authenticate() method...

Comment: You seem to have app_login defined which means supports() should work.  Even if there was some sort of csrf nonsense going on it should still reach the authenticate method.  You said it was a fresh app so there should not be any other listeners intercepting things.  Your success route is named dashboard but I assume you don't have any admin type packages loaded?  Any useful messages in the development server's console window?

Comment: @Cerad I checked the supports() method and found the problem... Though maybe you can help me with how  to deal with it. Since I am using wamp for development purposes, the getLoginUrl() method returns my full path: `/workspace/public/login`, but the getPathInfo() is just `/login` so the supports() method always return `false`... Any way I can deal with that? EDIT: I overrided the supports() method and thanges getPathInfo() to getRequestUri() and that fixed it... finaly... I will write the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I think you probably need an htaccess file to get rid of /workspace/public.  Probably going to mess you up in other places.  Better yet, just use the Symfony development server.  That is what it is there for.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was found in the AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator class supports() method. The method checks if the getLoginUrl() method returns full URI, while the getPathInfo() gives the extra path information after the URI. I had to override the supports() method and thange getPathInfo() with getRequestUri() and it worked.

```
public function supports(Request $request): bool
{
    return $request->isMethod('POST') && $this->getLoginUrl($request) === $request->getRequestUri();
}
```

Comment: It also seems to happen if you're behind a reverse proxy path ( public_url//prefix => internal_url) and implement trusted_headers + x-forwarded-prefix.