# Upgrade to new symfony authenticator system: can't log in anymore

Tags: php, symfony

Following an upgrade from Symfony 4 to the latest Symfony 5 version, I've tried upgrading my registration and login form guard thingies to become authenticator thingies.

After trying a lot of stuff, and using the `make:user` and `make:auth` commands again and again, I'm now in a situation where I have no warning, no error, just when I try to log in, nothing happens: it doesn't matter whether the username/password combination is correct or not, I just get back to the login form.

Here are the files I believe could be relevant to the issue:

config/packages/security.yaml

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    password_hashers:
        App\Entity\Player:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\Player
                property: email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800
                path: /
                always_remember_me: true
            switch_user: true

    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

src/Controller/SecurityController.php

```
<?php

    namespace App\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

    class SecurityController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
         */
        public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
        {
            // If the user is logged in, redirect them to their profile page.
            if ($this->getUser()) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('player_control_panel');
            }

            // get the login error if there is one
            $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
            // last username entered by the user
            $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

            return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
        }

        /**
         * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
         */
        public function logout()
        {
            throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
        }
    }
```

src/Entity/Player.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PlayerRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=PlayerRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class Player implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isVerified = false;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function isVerified(): bool
    {
        return $this->isVerified;
    }

    public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
    {
        $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

src/Security/LoginFormAuthenticator.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', "You are now signed in. Greetings, commander.");

        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_index'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

I just can't see what's going wrong, if you have an idea, or even if you can just give me an idea of how I could get an idea of what's going wrong, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: What you posted seems okay.  Check to see if the AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator::supports method is working as expected.  I have seen a few cases where the route's path info was not what was expected because of the way the server was configured.  You could also double check that the _csrf_token is getting posted.  And maybe simplify things a bit by commenting out the remember me, switch user and the admin access control sections.  You can add them back once you get things working.

Comment: I got problem with getLoginUrl behind a reverse proxy (path prefix): urlGenerator->generate provides a full path (with the path prefix, as seen in the browser address bar) so it doesn't match with supports() call that use the internal path (without the prefix).
There not much of a doc about this method usage (there's no more mention of it in Symfony 5.3 or higher doc :deprecated ?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that's a duplicate of [Symfony simple Login form with the new authentication method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68837184/symfony-simple-login-form-with-the-new-authentication-method-not-working) which I found a few minutes after posting this (I swear I searched before and didn't find it).

The issue is indeed the `supports()` method missing in the authenticator class, the one in the abstract login form authenticator apparently isn't sufficient. Adding that method fixed it:

in src/Security/LoginFormAuthenticator.php

```php
    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }
```

Full file:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): bool
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', "You are now signed in. Greetings, commander.");

        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_index'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you using bin/console server:start to develop your app?  As I mentioned in the other question, I still think that this problem indicates a misconfigured server which could end up causing further problems.  Maybe not.

Comment: @Cerad I don't, I use my own LAMP stack on a VPS, and most of its configuration is default, I don't even think I changed anything in PHP's configuration.

Comment: You might want to confirm that onAuthenticationFailure as well as the start method works as expected.  Both of the methods (along with supports) rely on getLoginUrl.  You change removes this dependency for the supports method but not the other two.

Comment: @Cerad Authentication fails successfully when invalid credentials are entered, but I'll check in more detail, thanks for the advice. :)